# How can one show that : $|u_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}|\le\frac{1}{4}|u_n-\sqrt{2}|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-linear-algebra

$U_n$ numerical sequence such that :
( For all natural numbers $n$ ) $U_{n+1}=1+\dfrac{1}{1+U_n}$ and $U_0=1$

How can one show that : $|U_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}|\le\frac{1}{4}|U_n-\sqrt{2}|$

I arrived to show that

$$|U_{n+1}-U_n|\le\frac{1}{4}|U_n-U_{n-1}|$$

Using the fact that function $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+x}$ is decreasing in interval $[1,\frac{3}{2}]$

Comment: Don't start with what you've arrived. Just plug $u_{n+1}$ directly into what you are asked to prove, while specifying proper domain of $u_n$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sqrt{2}$ .

Note that this isn't an ordinary number , it's the root of $t=1+\frac{1}{1+t}$ which looks exactly as the recurrence :

$$U_{n+1}-x=1+\frac{1}{1+U_n}-\left (1+\frac{1}{1+x} \right )=\frac{x-U_n}{(1+x)(1+U_n)}$$

Now we need only to prove that :

$$(1+x)(1+U_n) \geq 4$$

But $U_n \geq 1$ for every $n$ and $x>1$ so :

$$(1+x)(1+U_n) \geq 2 \cdot 2 =4$$