# convergence of $u_n = 1+ \frac{1}{u_{n-1}+1}$ to $\sqrt2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling to find a proof for: Convergence of $u_n = 1+ \frac{1}{u_{n-1}+1}$ to $\sqrt2$.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

edit: Here's what i've tried so far:

$(U_{n} -1)(U_{n-1}+1) = 1$

$U_nU_{n-1}+U_n-U_{n-1} -1 = 1$

$U_n(U_{n-1}+1)-U_{n-1}= 2$

$U_n = \frac{2+U_{n-1}}{U_{n-1}+1}$

$U_n = \frac{2}{(U_{n-1}+1)} + \frac{U_{n-1}}{U_{n-1}+1}$

Now i'm not sure how to proceed from this step.

Comment: $x=1+\dfrac1{x+1}\iff x^2=2$

Comment: Don't quite understand why you did that given it's a sequence. What's the theory that allows you to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are not allowed to perform that method if you do not know about the convergence of the sequence!!!!!!!

Comment: See also: [How can one show that : $|u_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}|\le\frac{1}{4}|u_n-\sqrt{2}|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1598681/272831)

Comment: Hi @SimplyBeautifulArt I had a look at that link and it doesn't really help me with the above. Any chance you could reopen this? The other is similar, but a different question.

Comment: Both links provide the necessary information to show the sequence converges. Edit your post to show what you've tried after looking through them so that we can help you with where you're specifically struggling.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I just noticed the 3 answers linked at the top. I missed this and was looking at the link you posted in comments. Having reviewed them, I don't understaand how they decided to pluck out the guess for sqrt(2) out of thin air (bit where they subtracted by sqrt(2). How do you know that it has to be sqrt(2)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt any thoughts on how to proceed from my working added above?

Comment: You can see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1304728/272831).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I saw that but one thing I don't understand is how it was decided to subtract both sides by $\sqrt2$. What's the rationale behind that? Thanks.

Comment: You know you want to show it converges to $\sqrt2$, so you should show that $u_{n+1}$ is closer to $\sqrt2$ than $u_n$.